# Google news topic url parameter list?

Tags: rss, feed, google-news

I'm currently trying to build a news reader that gets rss feeds from different google news topics and I found [this](http://i-tweak.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-news-search-parameters-missing.html) website that breaks down the url parameters pretty well, but under the `topic` parameter, the link that it has for a list of topics brings you to [this](https://support.google.com/news/answer/59255?hl=en) page which says nothing about topic keywords. The only topic key that I've been able to find is `tc` being the key for the tech topic.

Does anybody know where I could find a list of these topics or if the `topic=[topic]` parameter is deprecated what I could use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend of country.

Example *(for US)*:

- WORLD
- NATION
- BUSINESS
- TECHNOLOGY
- ENTERTAINMENT
- SPORTS
- SCIENCE
- HEALTH

[RSS business (US)](https://news.google.com/news/headlines/section/topic/BUSINESS?ned=us&hl=en)

> https://news.google.com/news/headlines/section/topic/BUSINESS?ned=us&hl=en

But, if you query other country, the topic will change.

Example (Colombia):

- WORLD.es_co
- NATION.es_co
- BUSINESS.es_co
- TECHNOLOGY.es_co
- ENTERTAINMENT.es_co
- SPORTS.es_co
- SCIENCE.es_co
- HEALTH.es_co

Here is the [RSS about economy/business in Colombia](https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/BUSINESS.es_co/Econom%C3%ADa?ned=es_co&hl=es):

> https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/BUSINESS.es_co/Econom%C3%ADa?ned=es_co&hl=es

Check too the **ned** and **hls** parameters added.